# Python heapq sorting for string list not correct?

Tags: python, sorting, heapq

I am wondering why not the heapq in python sort the strings in lexical order when using heappush?
Below is the code I tried. Anyone know why they print different order?

```
import heapq
string_list = ["TIA","AXA","JFK"]
result = []
for each in string_list:
    heapq.heappush(result, each)

print(result)
>>> ['AXA', 'TIA', 'JFK']

print(sorted(string_list))
>>> ['AXA', 'JFK', 'TIA']
```

Comment: Because creating a heap does not create a sorted list... Did you expect it to?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

Comment: Heap queue is minheap, it makes sure that min element in at the top of the queue, it doesn't sort list. Thanks, @juanpa.arrivillaga, confused.

Answer (score 1):

Heap queue is minheap, it makes sure that min element in at the top of the queue, it doesn't sort list.
If you want to sort your list using heapq, then you need to do the following:

```py
import heapq

string_list = ["TIA","AXA","JFK"]
heapq.heapify(string_list) # this will create max queue from your list
result = []
while string_list:
    result.append(heapq.heappop(string_list))
print(result)
```

But simpler and faster would be to just use in-place sort:

```
string_list.sort()
print(string_list)
```